# Image Saving time get error a generic error occurred in gdi+

Tags: c#

am using url for downloading images and save the current user login path but occurse error is 
a generic error occurred in gdi+.
becouse i think system geting path of this format `:-C:\\Users\\admin\\Pictures`
but i want `C:\Users\admin\Pictures` 
so please solve my problems to stackoverflow team

am using a this code and geting a error....

```
string userpath=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
            string Sourceurl = url;
            userpath += id;
            userpath += ".jpg";
            Bitmap varBmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(varBmp);
            varBmp.Dispose();
            varBmp = null;
            //do something
            newBitmap.Save(userpath, ImageFormat.Png);
```

shimpi mahesh 
pune.

Comment: You sure that's the error or is visual studio telling you that's the path

Comment: Did you at least try to search StackOverflow? There have been at least 5 questions I know that answer this. The path *of course* looks like `C:\\Users\\...` in the Debugger, as in C#, the backslash must be quoted. That's not the problem. The problem is that the bitmap is not yet loaded when you dispose of the variable and try to save.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) as in

```
string userpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "123" + ".jpg");
```

To view the value correctly don't rely on mouse over, that shows the escaped string, to see the reality use the magnify icon near the value, a new window will appear.